# How would I sort a file numerically when some lines are single-digits and others are double-digits?

Tags: sort

For Example suppose I have the following in a text file `myfile.txt`

```
Schwifty1
Schwifty2
Schwifty3
Schwifty4
Schwifty5
Schwifty6
Schwifty7
Schwifty8
Schwifty9
Schwifty10
... ect ect ect...
Schwifty20
Schwifty21
... ect ect ect...
Schwifty30
Schwifty31
```

using `sort` on this file will return something like:

```
Schwifty1
Schwifty10
Schwifty11
.........
Schwifty2
Schwifty20
Schwifty21
.........
Schwifty30
Schwifty31
Schwifty32
..........
```

I want it to actually be numerical based off the **number** attached to the end. Is there any way to accomplish this using the sort function?

Comment: One answer of that post uses the same option, but that question is more about renaming the files than actually sorting them. I think not duplicate.

Comment: There are ways to do it, it all depends on your input. With this particular input sample `sort -k1.9,1n` should do (that is the sort starting position is the 9th char). If you can't use a starting position then isolating the column to be sorted is the way to go...

Comment: cut -c9-10 a.txt |sort -n

Answer (score 8):

Use the version sort option.

```
sort -V source > destination
```

Comment: `-V` does not appear to be an option for sort on my server

Comment: try using the long option `--version-sort`. Also check what version of sort your are using `sort --version`. I'm using `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.22`

Comment: claiming that both of those are not legal options

Comment: @sharp sort -V works in my Debian 8.5 and does the job you need. It would be better to advise details of your OS & sort version. If your sort does not support operation similar to --version-sort option as explained for example here https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/coreutils/sort.1.en.html then you need to manipulate your file.